# Crop images in circle shape with border around it

Tags: android, image, border

I want to have my image in circle shape and a stroke around it.

I use this code to crop my bitmap in circle, but i don't know how to put a border/stroke around it.

```
    public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
            bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    // canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2,
            bitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
    //Bitmap _bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(output, 60, 60, false);
    //return _bmp;
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the `canvas.drawArc()` method. Make sure you set your paint style to `STROKE` and set a stroke width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Paint paintStroke = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG); // create anti-aliased Paint
paintStroke.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);             // define paint style as Stroke
paintStroke.setStrokeWidth(1f);                       // set stroke widht to 1 px
paintStroke.setColor(0xFF00FF00);                     // set color
canvas.drawArc(rect, 0f, 360f, true, paintStroke);    // draw arch from 0 to 360 degrees (i. e. closed circle)
```